# How to improve performance for pyspark job that is reading from cassandra and writing into s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, cassandra

I am reading data from cassandra table and writing into aws s3 bucket . It is taking 45 min to complete for writing 3 GB of parquet file in s3 . I am running pyspark job in aws emr .
Below are configurations:

```
"emr_cluster_core_instance_count": 2,
  "emr_cluster_core_instance_type": "c4.2xlarge",
  "emr_cluster_core_volume_size": 30,
  "emr_cluster_master_instance_count": 1,
  "emr_cluster_master_instance_type": "c4.xlarge",
  "emr_cluster_master_volume_size": 30,
  "emr_step_executor_cores": "2",
  "emr_step_executor_memory": "2G",
  "emr_step_driver_memory": "4G",
  "emr_step_driver_cores": "4",
```

**spark code:**
**reading data from cassandra:**

```
data = spark_session.read \
        .format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra') \
        .options(table=table, keyspace=keyspace) \
        .load()
    return data
```

as I am adding one column that calculates hash over few columns:

```
 df_wth_json_col = data \
        .withColumn('json_data', f.to_json(f.struct([data[x] for x in data.columns if x not in primary_k_list])))

 data_wth_hash= df_wth_json_col.withColumn("hash", md5('json_data')).drop('json_data')
 data_wth_hash.cache()


 data_wth_hash = data_wth_hash.coalesce(25)
```

**writing data into s3:**

`full_s3_data.write.parquet(full_path`)

Comment: remove coalesce, check how Cassandra behaves when you do the reading, check if Spark jobs are restarting - sometimes the nodes are overloaded when you're reading with default LOCAL_ONE, so using CL=TWO or QUORUM could provide better performance because they are reading slower. As I mentioned in previous answer, maybe it's easier to unload data into JSON or CSV using DSBulk, and then use small Spark job to convert it into Parquet

Comment: I have apache cassandra not data stax one . I have query why local_one might have performance impact in reading though CL setting higher adds latency as co-ordinator needs to compare replica data with digest .

Comment: DSBulk works just fine with open source Cassandra

Comment: when Spark reads with LOCAL_ONE, it reads with single node only, and when trying to read as much as possible, it often overloads the node, query timeouts, and Spark restart the job, re-reading the data.  When you read with higher CL, then the latency is increasing, but Spark doesn't overload the nodes, so the Spark jobs are not restarting, etc.  Check if you have restarted Spark jobs during execution.  45 min for 3Gb is very strange - in that time it's possible to process terabytes.